# How can I debug a crashing application on OS X?

Tags: macos, crash, games

I have a game installed from Steam on my Mac (Crusader Kings II).  The most recent patch from the developer has been having crashes and freezes on my Mac, and I'd like to help give the developer as much debugging information as possible (I'm an iOS developer myself).

One of the problems with the game involved the game completely freezing up.  To assist in debugging, I used the Time Profiler from Xcode Instruments and attached it to the game.  When it froze, I could see what exactly was using up processor time, and I've reported this to the developer.

However, the other problem with the game is a hard crash to the desktop.  Normally, when applications (like Xcode) completely crash, OS X will give me an error report that will include useful information, like the stack trace.  However, when this game crashes, I get nothing.  It just completely disappears.  The process is no longer in the Force Quit list, but I also get no crash report.

Is there any way, using Xcode Instruments, or any other means, to determine exactly what state the application is in in the instant just before it crashes?

My computer is a Mac Mini (late 2012 model) and I'm on OS X 10.10.1 if that matters.

Comment: I wish there were more users like you :)

Comment: Well, I choose to reward the game developers who give us excellent OS X games.  ;)

Comment: I guess the console shows nothing of relevance before the crash!

Comment: In the situation where only them game is out to lunch it is difficult to debug, as there's no "event" to trigger logging, etc. Depending on how completely the computer's locked up, you might be able to e.g. SSH in and check out what's going on while it's locked, but that'll only work if it's just the GUI that's locked.

Comment: I also assume you run the AHT extended and full RAM test to check for hardware.

Comment: @Buscar웃 To be clear, I'm not concerned about the situation in which the computer freezes.  I've got that one.  I'm concerned about the situation in which the game crashes without a crash report.

Comment: @nhgrif That is probaly a programming error and the program is exiting without telling the user rather than a crash. I have had games like that I think from Steam. In that case as far as macOS is concerned the program behaved correctly

Answer (score 5):

One possible way would be running:

```
sudo dtruss -n <app_executable>
```

where `<app_executable>` is the name of the executable file in the the app bundle in the `Contents\MacOS` folder inside the app.

For example, if you wanted to debug iTunes, you would first find out the executable name:

```
ls -alh /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/

drwxr-xr-x  5 root wheel 170 Mar 30 21:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 root wheel 374 Mar 30 21:01 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root wheel 102 Mar 30 21:02 iTunesHelper.app
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root wheel 29M Mar 29 02:01 iTunes <<<<<<<< this one
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root wheel 18K Mar 29 02:00 iTunesASUHelper
```

You can also do it by right-clicking an app in Finder and selecting **Show Package Contents**.

Once you figured out it is `iTunes` you can use the following command:

```
sudo dtruss -n iTunes
```

This will display a lot low-level info, but might contain something useful to identify the cause of a crash.

Other potentially useful built-in utilities are: **iosnoop**, **iotop**, **opensnoop**, **execsnoop**, **opensnoop** which are all based on **dtrace** which is also usable on its own. They all have man pages so you can use e.g. `man iosnoop` in a terminal for details on usage. All of them require `sudo`.

On the other hand, if you want to see what files are accessed by an app you could grep the output of `fs_usage`:

```bash
# display files accessed by google chrome
sudo fs_usage | grep -i chrome
```